# Segmentation fault in a vector<vector<Point> > in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, vector, computer-vision

I made a little piece of code which causes a segmentation error but I do not understand why.
Hope you guys can clarify.

Code:

```
   for(unsigned int i = 0; i < Objects.size(); i++)
   {

   if (Objects[i].size() > 10)
           Objects2[i] = Objects[i];
   }
```

Objects is declared as vector > because of the opencv function findContour().

Gr!

Comment: Is `Objects2` of the right size? What are you actually trying to do? There may be an easier way.

Comment: This code is part of a larger code which should detect people in an Aerial imagery. I made a SalientMap and find the contours in this map. Now I want to draw a boundary box around the contours I found.

Comment: problem is I find like 100 contours. There are a lot of small contours. I need to remove the small ones.

Comment: Code you provided is not enough to reproduce the problem. It might be in initialization of `Objects2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me guess. You didn't initialize `Objects2` to be of the correct size, therefore

```
Objects2[i] = Objects[i];
```

is an out-of-bounds access.

You might consider

```
Objects2.push_back(Objects[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the subscript operator does not throw an exception then it seems that the reason of the segmantation fault is statement

```
Objects2[i] = Objects[i];
```

You can substituted it for

```
Objects2.at( i ) = Objects[i];
```

and catch the exception that to determine what index is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

The area of contour can be calculated using [contourArea](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=contourarea#contourarea). Try:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Objects.size(); i++) {
    if (contourArea(Objects[i]) > 10) {            
        Objects.erase(Objects.begin() + i);
        i--;
    }
}
```